# Is it cheating to use 'static' when writing a recursive algorithm?

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

As part of a programming assignment, I'm required to write a recursive function which determines the largest integer in an array. To quote the exact task:

> Write a *recursive* function that finds the largest number in a given list of
>   integers.

I have come up with two solutions, the first of which makes two recursive calls:

```c
int largest(int arr[], int length){
    if(length == 0)
        return 0;
    else if(arr[length - 1] > largest(arr,length -1))
        return arr[length];
    else return largest(arr,length -1);
}
```

The second one makes only one, however it uses a static variable `n`:

```c
int largest(int arr[], int length){
    static int n = -1;
    if(length == 0)
        return n;
    else if (arr[length - 1] > n)
        n = arr[length - 1];
    return largest(arr, length - 1);
}
```

I was wondering whether it would be considered *cheating* use static variables for such a task. Either way, which one is considered better form? Is there a recursive method which tops both?

Comment: Are you assuming that all the numbers have to be positive? What is the largest of this list `-4, -3, -2` - it is not -1

Comment: Think about what the purpose of `static` is: to maintain a value *between* invocations. Within any given invocation, you're either returning `n` directly or setting it and then returning it from within a nested call (a glorified parameter pass). Your algorithm *doesn't* require the value to ever be stored across a return-and-reenter.

Comment: Bear in mind that the use of static vars brings automatic thread-unsafety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the excellent points in the three prior answers, you should practice having more of a recursion-based mind.  (1) Handle the trivial case. (2) For a non-trivial case, make a trivial reduction in the task and recur on the (smaller) remaining problem.

I propose that your proper base case is a list of one item: return that item.  An empty list has no largest element.

For the recursion case, check the first element against the max of the rest of the list; return the larger.  In near-code form, this looks like the below.  It makes only one recursive call, and has only one explicit local variable -- and that is to serve as an alias for the recursion result.

```
int largest(int arr[], int length){
    if(length == 1)
        // if only one element, return it
        return arr[0];
    else n = largest(arr,length-1))
        // return the larger of the first element or the remaining largest.
        return arr[length-1] > n ? arr[length-1] : n
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution - I wasn't sure at what point to cache the contents of the recursive call of my original code. Could you explain the syntax `arr[0] > n ? arr[0] : n`? I've never come across it.

Comment: Glad to be of help.  It takes most of us a lot of practice to think in such terms.  If you happen to have a *very* good optimizer, you don't even need the local cache: you write two calls, and the optimizer collapses the second to a temporary variable (implicit cache).

Comment: The funny notation is generically called the *ternary operator*.  This is an expression-level **if** statement: if the condition is true, the expression before the colon is the value; if false, the expression after the colon is used.  Thus, the reads like "if arr[length-1] > n return arr[length-1] else return n".  See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/14631/).  Yes, I edited my example and this comment to yield location length-1 instead of 0.  Oops.

Comment: As for your warning, I don't see the problem.  Does it have a line number for the first potentially uninitialized reference?  I would think that any modern complier (say, less than 25 years old) could handle this case.

Comment: It's referring to line 34; i.e. the "else"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112549/discussion-between-prune-and-luke-collins).

Comment: Changing to C99 fixed it. Thanks :)

Comment: This has a recursive depth of `length` and so not a good example of recursive function usage when much less depth can be had.

Comment: The `else` is not needed.

Comment: @chux: I know, but I often follow the OP's structure.  He used *return ... else*, so I followed suit.  Also, some instructors prefer the redundancy.

Answer (score 8):

I wouldn't say that it's cheating to use `static` variables this way - I'd say that it's incorrect. :-)

Imagine that you call this function multiple times on a number of different arrays. With the static variable introduced, the value of `n` never resets between calls, so you may end up returning the wrong value. Generally speaking, it's usually poor coding style to set things up like this, since it makes it really easy to get the wrong answer. Additionally, if your array contains only negative values, you may return -1 as the answer even though -1 is actually *bigger* than everything in the array.

I do think that the second version has one nice advantage over the first - it's much, much faster because it makes only one recursive call rather than two. Consider using the first version, but updating it so that you cache the value returned by the recursive call so that you don't make two calls. This will exponentially speed up the code; the initial version takes time Θ(2<sup>n</sup>), while the updated version would take time Θ(n).

Comment: I get what you mean, but I can't figure out at which point in the function the recursive call can be cached. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: I noticed that you're not declaring any non-`static` local variables in your recursive function. If you add in a local variable to a recursive call, each individual stack frame will get its own local copy of that variable. So imagine putting a local variable that stores the value of the recursive call. What could you do with that information?

Comment: I get that I can use the stored recursive call but I don't know at which point in the program I should store it :(

Comment: @LukeCollins I'm going to let you figure this one out on your own - it's a good exercise - but you ultimately want to compare the maximum of the rest of the array against the current element. Can you just write the code to do that? Make a call to get the maximum of the rest of the array, store it in a variable, and compare that against the current array element.

Comment: Do you mean adding something like `int n = largest(arr, length - 1)` and referring back to it? Because I get an error if I do that before the "else-if" in my code.  (That's what I tried to do initially)

Comment: @LukeCollins That's the right idea. If you're getting an error, it's likely due to something else - that code is perfectly legal (and, in fact, is a good idea!)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112548/discussion-between-luke-collins-and-templatetypedef).

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing *cheating* using a static inside function, recursive or otherwise.

There can be many good reasons for why to do so, but in your case I suspect that you are coming up with a wrong solution -- in as `largest` will only work once in the lifetime of the program running it.

consider the following (pseudo) code;

```
main() {
    largest([ 9, 8, 7]) // would return 9 -- OK
    largest([ 1, 2, 3]) // would return 9 ?? bad
}
```

The reason being that your `largest` cannot tell the difference between the two calls, but if that is what you want then that is fine.

**Edit:**
In answer to your comment, something like this will have a better big-O notation than your initial code;

```
int largest(int arr[], int length){
    int split, lower,upper;
    switch (length) {
      case 1: return arr[0];
      case 2: if (arr[1]>arr[0]) return arr[1]; else return arr[0];
      default:
              if (len <= 0) throw error;
              split = length/2;
              lower = largest(arr,split);
              upper = largest(arr+split,length-split);
              if (lower > upper) return lower; else return upper;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, the obvious solution is;

```
int largest(int arr[], int length){
    if (length <= 0) thor error;
    int max = arr[0];
    for (int i=1; i<length; i++)
       if (arr[i] > max) max = arr[i];
    return max;
}
```

which has no recursion at all

Comment: Oh of course. So is there a way to optimise the first non-static method?

Comment: You can binary chop the array in each recursive call to reduce the complexity from O(n*n) to O(log(n)*n)

Comment: The splitting approach is a lot better. Is there some way two recursive calls can be avoided though?

Comment: You can simulate it with a loop and an array simulating the stack to keep track of what have been tried -- but that is probably too much to answer with a code example here -- a simpler method, is to just run with a for loop across the array, just keeping track of the largest number so far.

Comment: @Soren I don't think that you need to do the full divide-and-conquer recurrence here to get an O(n) solution. Peeling off an element one at a time and recursing on the remaining array also works in time O(n) provided that you only make one recursive call at a time.

Comment: @templatetypedef -- Yeah, not sure what I was thinking --  it is all O(n) regardless of the implementation as long as every array element is only looked at once

Answer (score 3):

It is actually a terrible design, because on the second execution of the function does not return a correct result.

I don't think you need to debate whether it is cheating, if it is wrong.

The first version is also incorrect, because you return `arr[length]` instead of `arr[length-1]`. You can eliminate the second recursive call. What can you do instead of calling the same function (with no side-effects) twice with the same arguments?

Comment: So the first method is best?

Comment: I would compare the largest of the first half and with the second half

Comment: @LukeCollins I edited a paragraph to address your first version.

Comment: @Zulan I know it needs to be cached somehow, but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a recursive method which tops both?

Recursion gets a bad name when with `N` elements cause a recursion depth of `N` like with `return largest(arr,length -1);`

To avoid this, insure the length on each recursion is halved.
The maximum recursive depth is `O(log2(N))`

```
int largest(int arr[], int length) {
  if (length <= 0) return INT_MIN;
  int big = arr[0];
  while (length > 1) {
    int length_r = length / 2;
    int length_l = length - length_r;
    int big_r = largest(&arr[length_l], length_r);
    if (big_r > big) big = big_r;
    length = length_l; 
  }
  return big;
}
```

A sneaky and fast method that barely uses recursion as finding the max is trivial with a loop.

```
int largest(int arr[], int length) {
  if (length <= 0) return INT_MIN;
  int max = largest(NULL, -1);
  while (length) {
    length--;
    if (arr[length] > max) max = arr[length];
  }
  return max;
}
```